# Application stops debugging while generating report(crystal report)

Tags: c#, asp.net, crystal-reports, crystal-reports-2010, crystal-reports-8.5

Im having a web application and a windows application to generate report using crystal report, In some scenario the application stops debugging and throws an error 'vshost.exe has stopped working'

I tried many things which came across while checking for the solution,but i was not able to catch the exception and since i could not find the exact reason for the application to get crash i need a way were i can catch the exception.

The error occurs in the reportDocument.ExportToDisk method of crystal report.

While checking the system event log i found that the exception is happening from the crystal report.

```
   reportDocument.ExportToDisk(CrystalDecisions.Shared.ExportFormatType.PortableDocFormat, string.Format("{0}{1}", ReportDestinationPath, rec.GeneratedReportName + "_" + rec.ReportRequestID + "." + extension));
```

my question is about how can i catch that exception if it is a crystal report error?

> Faulting application name: ReportApp.exe, version: 1.0.1705.1, time stamp: 0x5a8d2727
>   Faulting module name: crpe32.dll, version: 13.0.12.1494, time stamp: 0x5443a343
>   Exception code: 0xc0000005
>   Fault offset: 0x0032ca2a
>   Faulting process id: 0xd4fc
>   Faulting application start time: 0x01d3ba39e4c4e89a
>   Faulting application path: C:\Program Files (x86)\ReportApp\ReportApp.exe
>   Faulting module path: C:\Program Files (x86)\SAP BusinessObjects\Crystal Reports for .NET Framework 4.0\Common\SAP BusinessObjects Enterprise XI 4.0\win32_x86\crpe32.dll
>   Report Id: 291c8194-262d-11e8-80e5-0cc47a9b8aeb
>   Faulting package full name: 
>   Faulting package-relative application ID: 
>   Application: ReportApp.exe
>   Framework Version: v4.0.30319
>   Description: The process was terminated due to an unhandled exception.
>   Exception Info: exception code c0000005, exception address 37B5CA2A

Comment: Could you update the question to include the block of code where the error occurs?

Comment: The application crashes while we try to export the report  kindly find the code @R.McMillan

Comment: any solution @shahabassageer ? I am getting same issue. It is crashing while setting datasource to the report and culprit is crqe.dll. not getting exact error instead it is crashing